# multiline textarea binding to a select

Tags: knockout.js

What I'm trying to do is to have each line of a textarea as an option on a Select, to achieve this I have computed binding with read and write option, when debugged (firebug) the model woks and updates perfectly but the html (select) doesn't update when options are modified or removed.   http://jsfiddle.net/SuperJohn/H9XYY/

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'description'"></select>
<br />
<textarea id="options" data-bind="value: opts"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
var viewModel = function ()
{
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([
        {"description": "First Option"},
    {"description": "Second Option"}
    ]),

    self.opts = ko.computed({
        read: function (){
        var spVals = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < self.items().length; i++)
            spVals += self.items()[i].description + '\n';
        return spVals;
    },
    write: function (taValue) {
        var spVals = taValue.split("\n");
        var len = (spVals.length > self.items().length) ? self.items().length : spVals.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
            self.items()[i].description = spVals[i];
        if (spVals.length > len){
            for (var i = len; i < spVals.length; i++)
                self.items.push({"description": spVals[i]});
        };      
    },
        owner: this
    })

    };
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your `description` properties to be `ko.observable` properties in order to make your code work:

```
self.items = ko.observableArray([
    {"description": ko.observable("First Option")},
    {"description": ko.observable("Second Option")}
]),
```

Of course you need to put out some `()` here and there to make it fully functional again but here is a fixed version of [your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JYLfH/).

To make the delete work you can have a cleanup step in your `self.opts` which cleans up the empty items:

```
self.items.remove(function (item) { 
    return !item.description();
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59U5Y/).